# strace shell command issue in Android

Tags: android, shell, adb, strace

I'm building a monitor app, which runs in background and logs the system calls executed by currently running application using the *strace* command.

```
String cmd="strace -p "+processID+" -o /mnt/sdcard/traceFile_"+processID+".txt";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Here *processID* is the PID of currently running process which is got from some other method implemented. It logs the system calls of the first app it monitors properly with all executed system call information. But when a new app is started(second one onwards), the *processID* is updated correctly, but the file **traceFile_processID** is written as an empty file.
I'm not able to figure out why its happening. Is it because the strace execution of first app monitored still there?? If so how I can execute a ^C to terminate that session and start a new one as in adb shell command prompt?? Plz help me.....

Comment: If you want to kill the strace process you should be able to do so by calling the [destroy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()) method on the `Process` returned by `exec()`.

Comment: Thanks for replying Michael..I tried this way..but didn't work.. Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);              pro.destroy();                                                     is this what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "^C" as you say, what you're really asking for is how to raise the signal called SIGINT to the given processID.  You can do that simply by `kill(processID, SIGINT);` - this is equivalent to pressing Ctrl-C on the keyboard for the target process.